# Best strategy to send mails with attachments, with a low memory footprint in the JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I would send an e-mail in Java with attached documents.
Sadly my JVM server has few heap memory, can send large file at the same time. I would reduce the memory footprint while I send my e-mail with attached file.

My approach would be store the file in a temporary location and send it to the smtp server as a stream, without loading the file in the heap of the JVM.

Which implementation could guarantee me this approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the JavaMail [MimeBodyPart.attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-) method, or using a [FileDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html) directly, JavaMail (well, actually JAF) will read the file using a FileInputStream into an 8K buffer, then write out the buffer, reusing the buffer to read the entire file.  It definitely will not read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Would you quote a reference documentation that would confirm this 8K buffer ? Google hasn't been my friend about that point!

Comment: It's only in the [DataHandler source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jaxws/file/d03dd22762db/src/share/jaf_classes/javax/activation/DataHandler.java#l302).

Answer (score 1):

1. Streams are the best approach, not buffered of course. Also removing any use of Strings keeping the code the most C-like as possible.
2. Limit the number of worker threads.
3. You can also use a more aggressive GC configuration.

Comment: Nice try, but GC choices will not help OP much. From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/tune_footprint.html read this - "*The choice of a garbage collection mode or static strategy does not in itself affect memory footprint noticeably, but choosing the right garbage collection strategy may allow you to reduce the heap size without a major performance degradation.*".

Comment: Considering you want to run with an heap as small as possible i wouldnt rely on javamail which implements a lot of things that you may not need.